# How to see time in ~/.bash_history file

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, history, bash-history

I added time to the `~/.bashrc` file, so now it shows me time when I execute `history` command like this:

```
  376  04/10/19 20:39:52 sudo cat ~/.bash_history
  377  04/10/19 20:40:04 date
  378  07/10/19 10:13:29 echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
  379  07/10/19 10:13:38 source ~/.bashrc
  380  07/10/19 10:13:54 history
  381  07/10/19 10:20:08 sudo vim /home/subir/.bash_history 
  382  07/10/19 10:20:29 sudo nano /home/subir/.bash_history 
  383  07/10/19 11:34:20 cd ..
  384  07/10/19 11:34:34 find | grep .bash_history
  385  07/10/19 11:34:48 cat ./subir/.bash_history 
  386  07/10/19 11:37:32 history
```

But when this session's data gets appended to `~/.bash_history` file then it shows something like this :

```
#1570201804
date
#1570423409
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
#1570423418
source ~/.bashrc
#1570423434
history
#1570423808
sudo vim /home/subir/.bash_history 
#1570423829
sudo nano /home/subir/.bash_history
```

What are the values after `#` ?. Can anyone help me deduce it's meaning or tell me a way to get timestamp in `~/.bash_history` file.

Comment: thats [epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/) you can convert epoch to other format with [date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) ex. ```date -d @1570201804 "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"```

Comment: @bac0n thanks for replying . Thank you for the help.Got it!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's Unix Timestamp / Epoch time - number of seconds passed from January 1st, 1970.

If you convert it to datetime, you will get:

```
$ date -d @1570201804
Fri Oct  4 18:10:04 EAT 2019
```

In UTC it is `10/04/2019 @ 3:10pm (UTC)` but since I am in East Africa, we get +3 time difference coming to `10/04/2019 @ 6:10pm (UTC)`

I guess your timezone is +5:30

Answer (score 2):

**Parse .bash_history containing timestamp ([awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)).**

first I cut the field at newline `-F \\n` and check for lines beginning with #epoch `$0 ~ /^#[0-9]+/`. Next I trim off first char `substr($1,2)` before formatting the epoch string `strftime("%d/%m/%y %T")`. Last I print the first part without newline `printf "%5d  %s "` so I can fetch the next line  `getline` that contains the commands and print them on the same line.

```
awk -F \\n '{ if ($0 ~ /^#[0-9]+/) {printf "%5d  %s ", ++i, strftime("%d/%m/%y %T", substr($1,2)); getline; print $0 }}' ~/.bash_history
```

**Output:**

```
    1  07/10/19 14:46:09 echo a
    2  07/10/19 14:46:28 echo b
    3  07/10/19 14:46:39 echo c
```